# Strong name signature not valid for this assembly

Tags: c#, vb.net, onclick, devexpress, publish

I've just started to get the following error in my clickonce application. I have just installed visual studio 2019 on my machine prior to this "Application validation did not succeed. Unable to continue.

when i click into details I get

```
    Activation of C:\Temp\ClickOnce\myApp\myApp.application resulted in exception.
    Following failure messages were detected:
Strong name signature not valid for this assembly DevExpress.Utils.v21.1.dll.
    I also get two warnings but I do not believe they are the cause of the problem
```

The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

Comment: Open cspropj file with notepad and set check signature to false.  I had similar issue last year and this is how I fixed the problem.

Comment: @jdweng i found this   <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: Was value false or did you change to false?  I don't remember if I removed item or set to false.  I also deleted some items in the bin folder when I fixed issue.

Comment: it was true but i change it to false but same problem

Comment: Delete the project bin folder (VS will rebuild).  Also check main project folder for files that are part of your source file or the csproj.  I had same issue last year and that is how I fixed issue.